# Define class loader for web application with Liberty

Tags: spring-boot, websphere-liberty

I have an  application Rest service it is a war I want to deploy it in Liberty profile.Currently I am packaging the app along with all spring jar inside war.
    But we want to create a shared library and move all those jar's into shared lib and reference that shared library using class loader from application.

```
server.xml
<application location ="restapp-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war" context-root="/myrestapp/mytestapp">
        <classloader commonLibraryRef="global"/>
    </application>

    <library id="global">
        <fileset includes="*.jar" dir="${server.config.dir}/lib/global"></fileset>
    </library>

Also I have placed all the jar dependencies under server/config/lib/global.

I am having below entries in my ibm-web-ext.xml which is in webapp/WEB-INF/

<web-ext
    xmlns="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee/ibm-web-ext_1_0.xsd"
    version="1.0">


    <reload-interval value="3"/>
    <context-root uri="/myrestapp/mytestapp" />
    <enable-directory-browsing value="false"/>
    <enable-file-serving value="true"/>
    <enable-reloading value="true"/>
    <enable-serving-servlets-by-class-name value="false" />

</web-ext>


Same config is working fine if I bundle all the jar's as part of WAR and place the war in dropins folder. But Sharedlibrary configuration is not working.
```

Comment: if I'm understanding your question correctly, you want to use your own custom classloader to load the shared library?  If my understanding is correct, there is no way to do that.  At least not using standard server.xml configuration.

Comment: @aguibert I need to define a class loader inside my application to load shared library.It's not custom class loader.When we build application as ear we defined our sharedLib and class loader in deployment.xml. But I am not use how to define it in war file with Liberty profile.

Answer (score 3):

You can define a shared library for your application in WebSphere Liberty by putting the following configuration in the server.xml:

```
<library id="springLib">
 <fileset dir="${server.config.dir}/libs/spring/" includes="*.jar"/>
</library>

<application location ="restService.war">
  <classloader commonLibraryRef="springLib"/>
</application>
```

With this configuration, code in the `restService.war` will be able to load classes from the `springLib` shared library.

See also: [Liberty: Shared Libraries](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/cwlp_sharedlibrary.html)

Comment: That should almost certainly be `<application>` rather than `<app>`.  It looks like an error in that Knowledge Center topic.

Comment: @aguibert I am using below configuration but due to some reason it's not working for me.<application location ="restapp-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war" context-root="/myrest/app">
    <classloader commonLibraryRef="global"/>
 </application>
    
    <library id="global">
        <fileset includes="*.jar" dir="${server.config.dir}/lib/global"></fileset>
    </library>

Comment: Re-reading your question you mention that you think the global library is pointing to $wlp_home/usr/servers/server/config/lib/global. Note that ${server.config.dir} is the directory of your server (where the server.xml is). Given this, is your library pointing to a valid directory?